# Grails Integration Test Does NOT Rollback

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

I'm learning grails from the book "[Grails In Action](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9781933988931)" and I'm trying to run integration tests from the examples.  In the book it says that each integration test function should roll back its operations as each test finishes.  It is NOT rolling back each transaction (as when I finish the database is dirty).  I tried to find out why and found found a property called "transactional".  Allegedly you set this property to true and it will make the test case transactional, but it doesn't appear to change the behavior.  I have included the code for the unit tests below.

I'm using grails 1.3.7 and connecting to a MySql database.  The tests run successfully, it just doesn't rollback.  Am I doing something wrong in this integration test that it skips the rollback?

**UserIntegrationTests.groovy:**

```
package com.grailsinaction

import framework.TestTools

class UserIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    static transactional = true

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testCreateUser() {
        TestTools.banner(log, "testCreateUser()")

        def user = new User(userId:"joe", password:"secret")
        assertNotNull user.save()
        assertNotNull user.id

        def foundUser = User.get(user.id)
        assertEquals 'joe', foundUser.userId
    }

    void testSaveAndUpdate() {
        TestTools.banner(log, "testSaveAndUpdate()")

        def user = new User(userId:"joe2", password:"secret")
        assertNotNull user.save()

        def foundUser = User.get(user.id)
        foundUser.password = 'sesame'
        foundUser.save()

        def editedUser = User.get(user.id)
        assertEquals 'sesame', editedUser.password
    }

    void testSaveThenDelete() {
        TestTools.banner(log, "testSaveThenDelete()")

        def user = new User(userId: 'joe3', password: 'secret')
        assertNotNull user.save()

        def foundUser = User.get(user.id)
        foundUser.delete()
        assertFalse User.exists(foundUser.id)
    }

    void testValidation() {
        TestTools.banner(log, "testValidation()")

        def user = new User(userId: 'chuck-norris', password: 'tiny')
        assertFalse user.validate()
        assertTrue user.hasErrors()

        def errors = user.errors
        assertNotNull errors

        errors.allErrors.each {
            log.info("field: ${it.field}, code=${it.code}, rejected=${it.rejectedValue}")
        }
    }
}
```

**User.groovy**

```
package com.grailsinaction

class User {
    String userId
    String password
    Date dateCreated
    Profile profile

    static constraints = {
        userId(size: 3..20, unique: true)
        password(size: 6..8, validator: {password, user ->
            return (password != user.userId)
        })
        dateCreated()
        profile(nullable: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        profile lazy: false
    }

    static hasMany = [posts : Post]
}
```

**Test Execution Log**

```
Testing started at 8:28 PM ...
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\apps\Grails\grails-1.3.7
Base Directory: C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\samples\lang-grails\hubbub
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 963ms.
Running script C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\apps\Grails\grails-1.3.7\scripts\TestApp.groovy
Environment set to test
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\samples\lang-grails\hubbub\target\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\samples\lang-grails\hubbub\target\test-reports\html
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\samples\lang-grails\hubbub\target\test-reports\plain
Starting integration test phase ...
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\samples\lang-grails\hubbub\target\classes
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\samples\lang-grails\hubbub\target\classes
[INFO ]20110417@20:28:42,959:grails.spring.BeanBuilder: [RuntimeConfiguration] Configuring data source for environment: TEST
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\samples\lang-grails\hubbub\target\test-classes\integration
-------------------------------------------------------
Running 4 integration tests...
Running test com.grailsinaction.UserIntegrationTests...
--Output from testCreateUser--
[INFO ]20110417@20:28:46,897:groovy.util.GroovyTestCase: Test Case: testCreateUser()
--Output from testSaveAndUpdate--
[INFO ]20110417@20:28:47,534:groovy.util.GroovyTestCase: Test Case: testSaveAndUpdate()
--Output from testSaveThenDelete--
[INFO ]20110417@20:28:47,568:groovy.util.GroovyTestCase: Test Case: testSaveThenDelete()
--Output from testValidation--
[INFO ]20110417@20:28:47,642:groovy.util.GroovyTestCase: Test Case: testValidation()
[INFO ]20110417@20:28:47,668:groovy.util.GroovyTestCase: field: password, code=size.toosmall, rejected=tiny
null
PASSED
Tests Completed in 1173ms ...
-------------------------------------------------------
Tests passed: 4
Tests failed: 0
-------------------------------------------------------
[junitreport] Processing C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\samples\lang-grails\hubbub\target\test-reports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\JMQUIG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\null90011239
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet C:\Users\jmquigley\workspace\apps\Grails\grails-1.3.7\lib\junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 415ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Users\JMQUIG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\null90011239
Tests PASSED - view reports in target\test-reports
Application context shutting down...
Application context shutdown.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tests (and services) are transactional by default so you only typically specify the static `transactional` property when it's `false`. If you haven't specified the Dialect it's probably auto-detecting MySQL but then the tables are created using the default engine which is probably MyISAM. MyISAM tables which are not transactional. Be sure to specify the InnoDB dialect whenever you use MySQL, e.g.

```
test {
   dataSource {
      dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
      driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
      username = '...'
      password = '...'
      url = '...'
      dbCreate = 'update'
   }
}
```

or if you're using MySQL for all environments, you can move it to the top-level, e.g.

```
dataSource {
   pooled = true
   dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
   driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the dialect setting.  Just note (for anyone else that may see this) that you have to drop the tables and recreate them for it to work if the tables were created before adding/changing the dialect setting.  The first time I tried it I just left the existing tables and it didn't work.  Thanks again, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

- In my case,

environment : STS(IDE), mysql(database)

grails integration test must rollback as you know(default).

'grails integration test' try to rollback as each test finished.

if your database do not support transaction..?

I change auto create database table to directly create table, with option Type=InnoDB. So I can solve it.

create table something( ... ) Type=InnoDB;

- I'm a Korean student. I can speak a little English. Please try to understand me.